# before_create :method, if: [:multiple, :constraints]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

on before_create, before_update, before_destroy methods, I would like to do an if: on multiple constraints, such as

```
before_destroy :lock_quantity, if: [:processed, :quantity_changed]
```

so that if it's been processed, the quantity cant change

(just in case:)

```
def lock_quantity
  errors.add :quantity, "You must revert the row before changing quantity"
end
```

so, is it possible to have multiple conditions for if:
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this should actually be like this...

```
before_update :lock_quantity, if: [:processed, :quantity_changed?]
```

Notice the question mark!

(just in case:)

```
def lock_quantity
  errors.add :quantity, "You must revert the row before changing quantity"
  false
end
```

pass false to stop saving